# The rite of the Red Heiffer and commentary by Moses Ben Maimon

Tags: rambam, parah-adumah

The rite of the Red Heifer ([Numbers 19:2-10](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.19.2-10?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0)) seems to me to be magic.  Is my understanding incorrect?
Does Moses Ben Maimon have a comment on this topic?

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain how it's more magical than immersion in a body of water for similar purification purposes?

Comment: The site is for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition. So we can't call one of the commandments magic. Rather it is a mitzvah without a reason or a “decree of the text גזרת הכתוב".

Rashi's comment agrees, “THIS IS THE ORDINANCE OF THE LAW — Because Satan and the nations of the world taunt Israel, saying, “What is this command and what reason is there for it”, on this account it (Scripture) writes (uses) the term חקה about it, implying: It is an enactment from before Me; you have no right to criticize it.”

But see Rashi on v 22 at the end.

Comment: A gentile asked Rabbi Yochanan ben Zakkai, "These rituals you do, they seem like witchcraft! You bring a heifer, burn it, crush it up, and take its ashes. [If] one of you is impure by the dead [the highest type impurity], 2 or 3 drops are sprinkled on him, and you declare him pure?!"

Comment: He said to him, "Has a restless spirit ever entered you?" He said to him, "No!" "Have you ever seen a man where a restless spirit entered him?" He said to him, "Yes!" [Rabbi Yochanan ben Zakkai] said to him, "And what did you do for him?" He sad to him, "We brought roots and made them smoke beneath him, and pour water and it flees."

Comment: He said to him, "Your ears should hear what leaves from your mouth! The same thing is true for this spirit, the spirit of impurity, as it is written, (Zachariah 13:2) "Even the prophets and the spirit of impurity will I remove from the land." They sprinkle upon him purifying waters, and it [the spirit of impurity] flees."

Comment: After he left, our rabbi's students said, "You pushed him off with a reed. What will you say to us?" He said to them, "By your lives, a dead person doesn't make things impure, and the water doesn't make things pure. Rather, God said, 'I have engraved a rule, I have decreed a decree (chukah chakakti, gezeira gazarti), and you have no permission to transgress what I decreed, as it says "This is a chok (rule) of the Torah."

Answer (score 4):

Moses Ben Maimon discusses the laws of the red heifer in detail in his code of law, in the section [“Laws of the Red Heifer”](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1517254/jewish/Parah-Adumah-Chapter-1.htm). In *Guide for the Perplexed* Part III he discusses the theological/philosophical underpinnings of the commandments. In Chapter 48 there he writes of the red heifer:

> The red heifer is called a sin-offering, because it effects the purification of persons that have become unclean through the dead body of a human being, and enables them to enter the Sanctuary [and to eat of hallowed things]. The idea taught by this law is this: Those who have defiled themselves would never be allowed to enter the Sanctuary, or to partake of holy things, were it not for the sacrifice of the red heifer, by which this sin is removed; in the same manner as the plate [which the high-priest wears on his forehead] atones for uncleanness, and as a similar object is attained by the goats that are burnt. For this reason those were unclean who were engaged in the sacrifice of the heifer or the goats which were burnt, and even their garments were unclean. The same was the law in the case of the goat that was sent away [on the Day of Atonement]; for it was believed that it made unclean those who touched it, because it carried off so many sins.
>
> ([Friedlander translation](https://sacred-texts.com/jud/gfp/gfp183.htm))